# Dual monitor setup with a USB C Hub

Tags: usb, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I want to buy a notebook, but unfortunalety it has only have two USB C  Thunderbolt ports. No USB A, No HDMI Out.
What to do if i want to connect this notebook to two external monitors? I think i need a USB C Hub with 2x HDMI Out.
My Question is - does such a hub need drivers? All offers on amazon & co. do not tell if this hardware has Linux / Ubuntu support. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "*Shopping or Hardware Recommendations*" are off-topic.  Ubuntu Forums allows those sort of *opinion* based questions.

Comment: I can provide some advice in here: I bought an asus zenbook and I've installed an ubuntu 22: it does not work the second monitor with such usb hubs.

Answer (score 2):

I have never needed any special Ubuntu drivers for using multiple monitors over USB-C.

But beware of portable docks that at first sight *appear* to support more than one monitor (they have several monitor sockets of different sorts) but in fact only support one monitor. My Dell dock supports multiple monitors without any special drivers, though the dock itself contains software which might need updates, so in a case like this you need to make sure you don't need a Windows program to do the update.